# SQL: How to get an Integar value of the previous month in the format YYYYMM based on the GETDATE() Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, if the todays date is 1/30/2019, I'd like to use the GETDATE() Function to return that date and set it equal to [Current_Date].  I'd then like to use the current date to assign the value of 201912 to the variable @SETMONTH that I've declared as an Integar.  Any help with code that is capable of doing this would be much appreciated.

```
@SETMONTH INT

--To assign a value to [Current_Date]

SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) [Current_Date]


UPDATE Table1

SET

Model_Month = --This is where I need a formula that can convert the date of 1/30/2020 to 201912
```

Comment: What logic do you need? Like, why would you assign the variable to December 2019 when today's date is January 30th 2020?

Comment: @JacobH my thought process is that I will only ever run this procedure for the previous month due to the way my company does reporting.  We have to wait until all the data is in for the month to run our procedures for the previous month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EOMONTH()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1), 112);
```

So, the update statement would looks like :

```
DECLARE @SETMONTH INT

SELECT @SETMONTH = CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1), 112)

UPDATE table1
      SET Model_Month = @SETMONTH
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!  Can I ask, what is the purpose of the "112"?

Comment: @oryan5000. . . 112 is a `century` that has ISO standard format `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: see here for full list of formats. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @YogeshSharma I'm getting the error message "Must declare the scalar variable ".  Is there a way to alter the CONVERT function so that the result is an Int instead of a String?

Comment: @oryan5000. . . Because we didn't declare variable `@SETMONTH`. We don't need to do conversion here. Let the `SQL` engine do the conversion.

Comment: FWIW @oryan5000 I don't think many people memorize that list of formats. I only keep 112 in memory because it's the only one I use with any regular frequency. Would not recommend committing them all to memory unless you spend a lot of time formatting global date values. The conversion chart is very helpful.